# I am getting Lex and Yacc program compilation error. Why?

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-construction, calculator, yacc, lex

I'm making a calculator program with [Lex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software)) and [Yacc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), but when I type 'cc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -ll -lm -ly' to compile on the terminal, I get the following errors. Where is it wrong?

I don't see an error, but it keeps saying this.
It should give me an *out* file as output, but it doesn't.

The warnings don’t matter, but errors are important for this subject.

This error:

```
call.l: In function ‘yylex’:
call.l:12:2: error: expected expression before ‘[’ token
   12 |  sin {return SIN;}
      |  ^
call.l:12:9: error: expected expression before ‘|’ token
   12 |  sin {return SIN;}
      |         ^
call.l:12:16: error: stray ‘\’ in program
   12 |  sin {return SIN;}
      |                ^
y.tab.c: In function ‘yyparse’:
y.tab.c:1256:16: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yylex’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 1256 |       yychar = yylex ();
      |                ^~~~~
call.y:31:35: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
   31 |           printf("Divide By Zero");
      |                                   ^
      |                                   ;
   32 |          }
      |          ~
y.tab.c:1465:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yyerror’; did you mean ‘yyerrok’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 1465 |       yyerror (YY_("syntax error"));
      |       ^~~~~~~
      |       yyerrok
call.y: At top level:
call.y:49:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
   49 | %%
      | ^~
call.y:58:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
   58 | }
      | ^
```

**This is my cal.y code**

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

%}
%union
{ double p;}
%token<p>num
%token SIN COS TAN LOG SQRT


/*deffff*/
 %left '+''-'
%left '*''/'
%nonassoc uminu
%type<p>exp
%%


ss: exp {printf(" ANSWER IS =%g\n" ,$1);}

exp :    exp'+'exp  { $$=$1+$3; }
       |exp'-'exp  { $$=$1-$3; }
       |exp'-'exp  { $$=$1*$3; }
       |exp'-'exp  {

               if($3==0)
               {
                   printf("Divide By Zero");
               }


               else $$=$1/$3;



                 }
        |'-'exp        {$$=-$2;}
        |SIN'('exp')'  {$$=sin($3);}
        |COS'('exp')'  {$$=cos($3);}
        |TAN'('exp')'  {$$=tan($3);}
        |LOG'('exp')'  {$$=log($3);}
        |SQRT'('exp')'  {$$=sqrt($3);}
        |num;
       |'('exp')'    {$$=-$2;}

%%

main()
{
    do
    {
        printf("\n Enter Expression :");
        yyparse();
    }while(1);
}

yyerror(char *s;)
{
    printf("SYNTAX error");
}
```

**This is my cal.l code**

It’s here somewhere. I don’t understand this error.

```
%{
    #include<math.h>
    #include"y.tab.h"
%}
%%

[0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+ {
            yyval.p = atof(yytext);
             return num;
             }

sin {return SIN;}
cos {return COS;}
tan return TAN;
log return LOG;
sqrt return SQRT;
[\t];
\n         return 0;
.             return yytext[0];
%%
```

Comment: There's no extra charge for using the space key. :-) Some of the places you've left it out produce errors. The rest just make your code hard to read.

Comment: And speaking of space characters, please verify that the line `[0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+ {` in your file `cal.l` does *not* start with a space. That's the only thing I can see which would produce those errors.

Comment: ... except for the error reported at line 31, which is actually caused by the stray semicolon in `yyerror(char *s;)`. While you're fixing that, add the return type of `yyerror` (it should return `void`) and `main` (should return `int`). In this century, C doesn't allow you to.omit return types or variable declarations.

Comment: ... and declare `yylex` and `yyerror` early in your `cal.y` (right after the `#include`s).